spring sts-3 MVC pattern 404 not found error
HTTP Status 404 – Not found
Type Status Report
Description The Origin server has not found the current representation for the target resource, or does not want to reveal whether it exists.
your text
I've tried project-clean as well, and I've also changed the route from servers-module-path to /, but it didn't work at all.
How can I overcome this error?
Here is my web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee https://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Handle UTF-8 encoding issues -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilterUTF8</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilterUTF8</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Bean related settings -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>


</web-app>

Here is the error message.
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'USERS'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: USERS
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:118)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:78)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:144)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:136)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:126)
... 58 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'USERS'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: USERS
at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:128)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveAlias(BaseBuilder.java:150)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:116)
... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: USERS
at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:226)
at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:103)
at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:322)
at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:124)
... 64 more
Please advise how to resolve the error.

All your questions on SO lack context that would help someone else understand what you're doing, your setup and what you've tried to figure out what could be wrong. I want you to succeed but put yourself in the position of others and imagine how challenging it would be to help you if you've left out so many key points
